# Java - Split a string to an array

Tags: java

I have a number that is submitted by the user.
I want to make something like this: `1568301`
to an array like this: `1, 5, 6, 8, 3, 0, 1`.

How can I do this without adding "," between every digit or something like that? (type int).

Thanks.

Comment: When you say *(type int)*, do you mean that you want the array to be of type int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Split with "" 
It'll be like this:

```
String test = "123456";
String test2[] = test.split("");
for (int i = 1; i < test2.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(test2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for an input of "" otherwise this will blow up!

Answer (score 9):

```
String str = "123456";
str.toCharArray();
```

will do roughly what you want. A more complex version using a regular expression is:

```
String str = "123456";
str.split("(?<!^)");
```

which uses a negative lookbehind (`split()` takes a regexp - the above says split on anything provided the element to the left isn't the start-of-line. `split("")` would give you a leading blank string).

The second solution is more complex but gives you an array of `Strings`. Note also that it'll give you a one-element empty array for a blank input. The first solution gives you an array of `Chars`. Either way you'll have to map these to `Integers` (perhaps using `Integer.parseInt()` or `Character.digit()`?)

Answer (score 3):

`"1568301".toCharArray()` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

cant you simply populate the array by iterating over the String ??

```
char[] arr = new char[str.length];
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
   arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
}
```

or even better

```
char[] arr = "0123456".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the values in an array of integers:

```
String str = "1568301";
int[] vals = new int[str.length];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    vals[i] = Character.digit(str.charAt(i), /* base */ 10));
}
```

The second parameter of `Character.digit(char, int)` is the number base. I'm assuming your number is base 10.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is in `String` format, you can simply do this:

```
    String str = "1568301";
    char[] digitChars = str.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are expecting something like this

```
    String ss ="1568301";
    char[] chars = ss.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking at to have an array of int.

I would suggest to have the following code :

```
String str = "1568301";
int [] arr = new int[str.length()];
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
  arr[i] = str.charAt(i)-'0';
}
```

Comment: why negative, can someone please explain?

Comment: I didn't mean to downvote your answer, but the site won't let me change my vote until you've edited your answer. If you add even a single space, I can fix my vote.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry for the clumsiness.